# Implementing Xaudio2 for windows phone 8 application

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, xaudio2

I am new to coding for windows phone 8, but have coded a lot in python before.  I am trying to make an application that uses Xaudio2 to generate a sine wave in real time and loop it infinitely as a drone pitch.  I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 and writing the application in C++ and XAML.  I  have figured out the graphical interface, which was not very hard, and tried using MediaElement to loop a short sound file to make the constant pitch, but there was a small gap in the sound every time the file restarted.  I read that using Xaudio2 could remove the gap and even generate the sound in real time without the need for a recorded sound (since I am concerned about memory) without any gaps.  This sounds like exactly what I needed, but I have had extreme troubles with Xaudio2.  I have looked at tutorials, as many as I can find, but I am not sure how to start the function, how to call the function, or where the code even goes on the page.  I am assuming it goes on the C++ page, but I don't even know that.  What I am trying to do is really simple, but I cannot get started because I do not know how to use this API in my code.  If anyone could help me to figure out how to get Xaudio2 started and working in my code, that would be really amazing!

Comment: First, you should look at using Windows phone 8.1 and VS 2013 instead of VS 2012 / Windows phone 8.0. Second, take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki)

Comment: I have a windows phone 8.0, so coding for another version is not really an option.  Also, the link you provided seems helpful but is also too complicated for me.  I just want to be able to use Xaduio2 to generate sine tones, and that seems to be really difficult to do.